# モニタやテレビなどの外部出力デバイスがない状態でラズベリーパイのプライベートIPアドレスを調べるには？

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

ラズベリーパイを購入したけれど家にテレビもモニターもなかった場合はルーターがあってもSSH接続できないんでしょうか？
ラズベリーパイをルーターに繋いで同じネットワーク内に接続した場合、
SSHポートをポートスキャンなどでプライベートIPアドレスを割り出して、接続することは可能なんじゃないでしょうか？

ラズベリーパイのOSは `raspbian` がインストールされており
ユーザー名は`pi`, パスワードは `raspberry`, つまりデフォルトのままに設定してあると仮定して
デフォルトの`22`番ポート(SSH)が開いてるコンピューターが同じネットワーク内に存在するか調べたいんです（`raspbian`はインストールするとデフォルトで`22`番ポートが開いている）。

```
nmap -p 22  192.168.*.*
```

実際に友達に家に押しかけて、この`nmap` コマンドを使用して同じネットワークの `22`番ポートがあいているコンピュータを調べたんですがこちらの不具合なのかラズベリーパイのプライベートIPアドレスを特定することはできませんでした（あと 256x256 のスキャンを行っているためか非常に時間がかかります・・・）

ポートスキャンでおなじネットワーク内のラズベリーパイのプライベートIPアドレスを特定できますか？

Answer (score 2):

家庭用ルーターがあるのであれば、それにログインして `DHCP` 払い出しログを見るといいでしょう。
ついでに `DHCP` 固定アドレス払い出し設定に `Raspberry Pi` の `MAC` アドレスを登録しておくと
毎回調査しなくて良くて簡単になるでしょう（オイラんちではそうしています）

Answer (score 1):

arp-scan というツールを使うと、LAN内の機器の、IPアドレス・MACアドレス・機器の製造メーカー、が調べられます。